# Splitting a full name into three variables within SQL

Tags: function, select, db2

I have a the following table structure

```
FirstName                Surname
Joe Jay Blog             Pepper
Jane Jay Bibs            Salt
Jim Jack Jones Snr       Sugar
```

What I am trying to do is take the value in first name and take everything before the first space into "first", everything between the first and second spaces and move it to "middle" and everything after the 3rd space in "end".

So for my last record:

```
first = Jim
second = Jack
third = Jones Snr
```

I can satisfy my first requirement with the following below:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(FirstName, 1,LOCATE(' ',FirstName)) AS first
```

But that seems to be as fair as I am currently.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work :P

First get firstname and group the middle+lastname, and just do the same again with the result to get the middlename with `LEFT` and lastname with right.

```
SELECT
  name, 
  firstname, /*already got this one*/
  LEFT(middle_last_name, INSTR(middle_last_name, ' ')-1) AS middlename, /*do the same LEFT to get middlename*/
  RIGHT(middle_last_name, LENGTH(middle_last_name)-INSTR(middle_last_name, ' ')) AS last_name /*get the remaining chars for lastname*/
FROM (

    SELECT *, 
    LEFT(name, INSTR(name, ' ')-1) AS firstname, /*Simply get the firstname with left*/
    RIGHT(name, LENGTH(name)-INSTR(name, ' ')) AS middle_last_name /*group the rest for this sub-query*/
    FROM users
    );
```